# Typescript is asking for an index signature on nested, Zod-validated, object which is coming in from API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Typescript 4.4.4, Next.js 11.1.2, Zod 3.9.3

Typescript is complaining with:
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type <Review Type> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type <Review Type>`

I understand how to add type signatures to objects that I am constructing and have done so with many object in this project.

What is strange about this case is that it is complaining on an object which comes in from an API call and which is validated by Zod long before this code sees it. The review object should/is not altered or accessed prior to the point that the affected code is run, aside for validation.

As far I have read there is no way to add index signatures to Zod schemas, though maybe I am missing something?

The specifics:

Zod schema which is associated with the complaint:

```
export type Review = z.infer<typeof Review>;
export const Review = z.object({
  id: z.string().uuid(),
  burnTime: z.number(),
  citrus: z.number(),
  earthy: z.number(),
  ethereal: z.number(),
  floral: z.number(),
  fruity: z.number(),
  herbal: z.number(),
  pricePaid: z.number(),
  rating: z.string(),
  reviewBody: z.string(),
  savory: z.number(),
  smokey: z.number(),
  spicy: z.number(),
  sweet: z.number(),
  woody: z.number(),
  yearPurchased: z.number().nullable(),
  createdAt: z.string(),
  user: z.object({ username: z.string() }).optional(),
});
```

The Review is passed into the component (called RadarChart) with a bunch of other props. In order to ease prop type validation I made a ReviewChart type, which packages up all the passed props (including the nested Review schema) and which looks like this:

```
export type ReviewChart = {
  <A bunch of values>
  review: Review;
  <Some more values>
};
```

Validation with the ReviewChart type does not fail at any point.

The props of the RadarChart component look like this:

```
const RadarChart = ({
  <A Bunch of props>
  review,
  <Some more props>
}: ReviewChart) => {
```

The line that is causing the complaint is in the RadarChart component at a point which accesses the Review object. This line just extracts a subset of the Review values into a separate object which is then used to build out a D3 chart. The failing line is the third line shown here, with typescript pointing to 'review[averageProperty]':

```
propertiesList.forEach((property: string) => {
        let averageProperty = `${property}Avg`;
        incenseProperties[property] = review[averageProperty] as number;
      })
```

FWIW, incenseProperties is declared a few lines above as:

```
const incenseProperties: { [index: string]: number } = {};
```

This code runs fine.
The way I read all of this is that when the `averageProperty` string-typed variable attempts to access the value on the `review` object there is no index signature on `review` so TypeScript complains. This all seems simple enough, and yet I can't figure out how to fix it. It makes me wonder if there is something else going on, and yet here a day on I'm not sure where to look.

What confuses me even more is that none of the other Zod validated schemas have had any issues with index signatures or object access, which suggests to me that they infer the index type(?). The only aspect of this case that seems different from the others is that the Review object is nested within ReviewChart.

So my question(s): Is there a way to apply an index signature to a Zod schema? If not is there some other way to apply an index signature to the Review object at some point? Is there something else going on here?

Code can be found here: https://github.com/perfidiousscript/incense_app/tree/master/client

Other, possibly relevant information:
tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending two days trying to solve this I found out that in order to access an object with a dynamic variable (as attempted above) the variable must be typed inside the bracket.

In this case it would look like this:
`incenseProperties[property] = review[averageProperty keyof Review] as number`

More on this here: https://www.nadershamma.dev/blog/2019/how-to-access-object-properties-dynamically-using-bracket-notation-in-typescript/